# Extremely minor tagging nitpick

Tags: discussion

Can we try to separate words in tags with hyphens? I see a 'bestpractice' and a 'globalvariables' tag already being used; to my mind, those should be 'best-practice' and 'global-variables'.

Yes? No? Thoughts?

Comment: Agree. Once we build up enough rep we can start setting up tag synonyms which will solve this problem :)

Comment: That was me :)  I guess it's a hangover from Flickr tagging (although I think they've changed that now). To me, tags should always be single words, no hyphens etc. But that's my personal opinion and I'm not particularly bothered about doing it a different way if that's the consensus.

I also see that hyphens are used on StackOverflow so I guess that's the proper way to go.

Comment: Nateronn already addressed this in an earlier meta thread here http://meta.expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1/which-tags-should-be-available